# Making a new database from an existing project in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have little experience with entity framework. I have been given an ASP.net web application and it has a database which written in entity frameworks and it runs in the person local computer. I would like to create a new database which contains all of the information (tables, data, etc) inside the database.

i have tried to change the connection string to my localDB but i have no idea on how to create the tables inside my localdb.

i have tried to search for a way but it does not give the answer that i am looking for. Can anybody help me with this problem or maybe someone can direct me to the solution which are already there for my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- First Change the  "Catalog=DBName" in connection string ,
- then open package manager console type command update-database, press enter.
  It may help you creating new database.
- If it will show the error regarding migration.
- Write command add-migration press enter, then provide a name to the migration.
- Now again write command update-database and wait for the success message until seed is running.

Comment: i manage to create all the tables when i run the application. I change the server into (localdb)\v11.0 and then run it, suddenly the tables are created. thank you for answering the question!